# Installing another source distribution in setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a dependency that's not on `PyPi`, but I have it in a source distribution tar file. Is there anyway to get `setup.py` to use the tar to install the dependency?

This doesn't work because `dependency.tar.gz` is not available after the project gets into an sdist:

```
from setuptools.command.install import install

class MyInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        os.system('pip install -U dependency.tar.gz')


setup(
      ...
      cmdclass={'install': MyInstall}
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setuptools documentation actually covers installation of dependencies that aren’t registered in PyPI.

http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi